# Polymer template repeat group

Tags: templates, polymer, repeat, web-component

Is there a way to do grouping in a polymer repeat template? I have a list of items with doc.name and doc.manualType, but I want to group a list of items so the manualType only displays once per group instead of for each item.

Or how do I update my binding to have a previousManualType so I can only display the manualType if it's different than the previous manualType.

```
<template id="docListTemplate" bind="{{searchResults}}">
   <div class="vGroup">
      <core-selector id="selector" class="list" multi selected="{{multiSelected}}">
         <template repeat="{{doc, i in data}}" {previousManualType:''}>
            <template if="{{doc.manualType!=previousManualType}}">
               <h1>{{doc.manualType}}</h1>
            </template>
            <div class="cb item">
                {{doc.name}}
            </div>
         </template>
      </core-selector>
   </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I can't change the data structures as I'm pulling the data from a JSON web service. Is there a way to update previousManualType using a computed property?

Comment: Polymer 0.5.1 adds experimental grouping on core-list, but it still requires data structures to be set up correctly first.  https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
<template id="docListTemplate" bind="{{searchResults}}">
   <div class="vGroup">
      <core-selector id="selector" class="list" multi selected="{{multiSelected}}">
         <template repeat="{{manualType in ManualTypes}}">
            <template repeat="{{doc, i in manualType.data}}">
              <h1>{{doc.manualType}}</h1>

              <div class="cb item">
                {{doc.name}}
            </div>
         </template>
      </core-selector>
   </div>
</template>
```

You need to prepare the data structures accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As Gunter pointed out the data structure seems to be the keypoint.
If you have no control over the input, then you will need to transform it.
You could user underscore / lodash to groupBy

http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy

https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy